# How do I loop through rows of subform in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm pretty new to VBA and not quite sure how to achieve the following need. I want to loop through either all rows or columns and get the their values. For Instance, If I want to get the two values in ProductCode column, how should I approach that. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *RecordsetClone*:

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form.RecordsetClone

While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs!YourFieldName.Value 
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: By the way, is it necessary to close Recordset and re set it to nothing?

Comment: No. VBA will normally take care of the garbage handling for you. It is mostly to indicate to yourself, that you are done with recordset.